Checking for Existence of Solution to System of Algebraic Non-linear Equations
I was wondering if anyone knows how one would go about solving or really just checking for the existence of a solution to a system of equations like this
$\sum_{i} x_i = a_1$
$\sum_{i<j} x_ix_j = a_2$
$\sum_{i<j<k} x_ix_jx_k = a_3$
$\sum_{i<j<k<l} x_ix_jx_kx_l = a_4$
...
Where there could be a finite or an infinite number of terms.
(all values are real numbers)
Or if someone could tell me how hard of a problem this is.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050431/prove-coefficients-of-polynomial-are-elementary-symmetric-polynomials

Update, so I think I have figured out an approach for this.
I will demonstrate for 4 terms,
we have
(1) $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = a_1$
(2) $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4= a_2$
(3) $x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4 = a_3$
(4) $x_1x_2x_3x_4 = a_4$
we write equation (2) as
(2.1) $x_1(x_2+x_3+x_4) + x_2x_3 + x_2x_4 + x_3x_4 = a_2$
using (1) we have
(1.1) $x_2+x_3+x_4 = a_1-x_1$
so equation (2.1) becomes
(2.2) $x_1(a_1-x_1) + x_2x_3 + x_2x_4 + x_3x_4 = a_2$
Then we write equation (3) as
(3.1) $x_1(x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4)+x_2x_3x_4 = a_3$
And using (2.2) we get that this becomes
(3.2) $x_1(a_2-x_1(a_1-x_1))+x_2x_3x_4 = a_3$
Then finally equation (4) becomes
(4.1) $x_1(a_3 - x_1(a_2-x_1(a_1-x_1))) = a_4$
Which becomes
(4.2) $x_1^4-a_1x_1^3+a_2x_1^2-a_3x_1+a_4 = 0$
And due to symmetry, this is true for all $x_i$, and the pattern seems pretty clear at least for a finite number of terms.
Additionally, it seems like from looking into it more, for the most part, there is only a solution if all the zeros of the polynomial are real.
